# NonLinearNavigationService and Toolkit Page Transitions

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm currently using the NonLinearNavigationService Class and the toolkit page transitions in my project, I noticed a bug when using the NonLinearNagivationService, the transition effect won't play well and I'm looking for a good solution for the issue.
I've read in the WP7 developers blog that they're working to support page transitions in the next version of the NonLinearNavigationService but still no updates.
I hope that someone has found a workaround for this issue.

Comment: can you please show something which demonstrates the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: well, I'm using page turn transition effects in the main page<br> when navigating back to the main page, the page first renders before the animations starts.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see that behavior if you're doing something like this:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        // Update your page
    }
```

One way to address it is to hook into the BeginTransition event on the NavigationInTransition:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TransitionService.GetNavigationInTransition(this).BeginTransition += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_BeginTransition);
    }

    void MainPage_BeginTransition(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update your page
    }
```

Your update logic won't run until the 'out' transition is completed and the 'in' transition is getting ready to run.

Comment: All that being said, Waleed, you are right - there's a fundamental issue with NonLinearNavigation. Whenever NonLinearNavigation recursively calls GoBack, you see the page transitions quickly in reverse. NonLinearNavigation's 0 Opacity fix for flicker doesn't work because the Transitions keep setting the opacity back to 1.